# How to get Caps Lock status on remote computer using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have tried the following command but I only get a value of `False`:

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01  -ScriptBlock {[console]::CapsLock}
```

When I run `[console]::CapsLock` locally the command works.

Comment: Eh, caps lock is not a "system-wide" setting - what exactly are you trying to assess here?

Comment: I need to see if the remote computer has its Capslock key on or off. I dont have to change the status i just need to verify what the status is on capslock and numlock.

Comment: Right, but that question _does not make sense_ - what would you expect on a Terminal Server with three users connected, 2 of whom doesn't have Caps Lock on - should `[console]::CapsLock` return `1/3`?

Comment: As Mathias pointed out - the question doesn't make a lot of sense. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: for my purposes i only need to worry about 1 user.

Comment: My guess is that this is really an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

## Using`[Console]::CapsLock`

The `[Console]::CapsLock` property can be read to get whether `CapsLock` is On or Off (`$true` or `$false`):

```
[Console]::CapsLock
```

You can also check the state of `NumLock` with `[Console]::NumberLock` as well.

## Using MS Word

Seems that the remote session doesn't reflect whether `CapsLock` is on or off based on whether the physical keyboard has it on or off.

I was able to find another method but don't have a way to test it myself, and it requires Microsoft Word to be installed:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"

# Check CapsLock
$word.CapsLock

# Check NumLock
$word.NumLock
```

## Using the `System.Windows.Forms` Namespace

A third method that might work for your needs would be to use the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace to read the caps lock setting.

```
# Make System.Windows.Forms available in Powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Check CapsLock
[System.Windows.Forms.Control]::IsKeyLocked( 'CapsLock' )

# Check NumLock
[System.Windows.Forms.Control]::IsKeyLocked( 'NumLock' )
```

## Using the Win32 API

You can also check the state using the Win32 API:

```
# Compile some quick C# so we can `P/Invoke` to the native library
$signature = @"
[DllImport("USER32.dll")]                            
public static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);
"@
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Kernel32 -Namespace Win32 -Passthru

# Check CapsLock
[bool]( $Kernel32::GetKeyState(0x14) )

# Check NumLock
[bool]( $Kernel32::GetKeyState(0x90) )
```

`0x14` is the key id for `CapsLock` and `0x90` is the key id for `NumLock`. [See this page for more information on making use of this API from .NET](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetKeyState), and [this page for the documentation of GetKeyState itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate).

## Doing it remotely

I could not find any reliable methods of doing this remotely, which makes sense, as `CapsLock` is a per session setting - not a system wide one. Even assuming there is a way to get the `CapsLock` status for a given active session, you could have several user sessions on one remote system at once, and it becomes difficult to know which session to look at for its `CapsLock` status.

Comment: OP already said this doesn't work (or rather, it doesn't meet their expectations) :)

Comment: Maybe I should read the question next time and not just the title :)

Comment: Yea this gives me a False even through the remote computer has Capslock on

Comment: I'm not finding any other methods for checking caps lock or num lock status.... unless Microsoft Word is an option.

Comment: Last I checked, virtual keyboard state is per logon session, not per "physical computer" :)

Comment: @BendertheGreatest still getting the False return even though caps lock is on using  PS C:\Users\TAadmin>      Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock { $word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application" ; $word.CapsLock}
False

Comment: I added a third method. If that also doesn't work, then the answer might be "you can't", since Caps Lock is really a session thing. It's not turned on system wide as someone else already said.

Comment: got the same result maybe theres a work around i can do that wont require having to install something onto the remote computer.

Comment: I added one last possible method but I don't think it'll yield any different results. You're welcome to try the `Win32` method and see if that works for you or not.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest yea it gave the same results

Comment: Unless you can inspect the state of a connected keyboard directly as opposed to checking the state of the virtual keys, I don't think this is possible. That said if you find a solution that works I'm interested in learning about it.