# why [CONSOLE]::NumberLock is not working in remote destop system

Tags: windows, powershell, wsh

when i run below command it works fine in my local system but don't know why it not working in remote aws server

```
@start /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden  -command "IF ([console]::NumberLock -eq 'True'){$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}')}"
```

on futher test i found that this line is not working [console]::NumberLock -eq 'True' on aws server but work perfectly in my local system
so i trie to check what output product just this line of code ([console]::NumberLock -eq 'True' ) in aws server and i found that it  produce correctly in caplock off it give output like :- False
and in caplock On it give output like True ... i tried various thing but none of them work

note : - local system as well as aws system is run on window 10 is there any other powershell command to achieve same

Comment: does the remote version of PoSh support that call? not all hosts support the `[console]` class ... and not all that support it support ALL of the methods.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes i check it by run {console] separately in powershell and it give correct value

Comment: bipin, @Lee is trying to point that the `[console]` class isn't available when you execute code _remotely_, using PowerShell remoting.

Comment: mklement0 @Lee sorry, for  misunderstood , ok so what other option available which i can use

Comment: @bipin - it looks like wscript won't tell you the status of that key. [*sigh ...*] instead, you may need to read the registry for that user.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey how can you provide some sample code for using registry

Comment: @bipin - do a search for `registry numlock setting` and for `powershell read registry` for what to change & how. [*grin*]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Caps Lock status on remote computer using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822434/how-to-get-caps-lock-status-on-remote-computer-using-powershell) *(not numlock but still applies)*.